# wppot gulp change path

Tags: gulp, pot

I have next compiled code:

```
#: path/from/gulp-folder/to/project-folder/tpl.default.php:121
msgid "Email"
msgstr ""
```

But I need:

```
#: tpl.default.php:121
msgid "Email"
msgstr ""
```

My gulp task:

```
return gulp.src( pathToProject + '/**/*' )
    .pipe(sort())
    .pipe(wpPot( {
        domain        : text_domain,
        package       : packageName,
        bugReport     : bugReport,
        lastTranslator: lastTranslator,
        team          : team
} ))
.pipe(gulp.dest('/languages/'))
```

How I can change this compiled code?